# Centroid of a rotational solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Let $C$ be the region of the plane under the graph of the function $f(x)=2-e^x$ and let $V$ be the rotational solid obtained by rotating $C$ around the $x$-axis. If the density of $S$ is given by $\rho(x,y,z)=e^{-x},$ find the $x$ component of the centroid of the rotational solid $S$.

My work:

I used the cylindrical coordinates $\begin{aligned}x&=x,\\y&=r\cos\varphi\\y&=r\sin\varphi\\\varphi\in[0,2\pi].\end{aligned}$

The Jacobian is then $J_\psi(x,r,\varphi)=r.$

For the bounds for $r,$ I considered an intersection of the solid and the plane in which lie the $x$-axis and the line $\ell:=\operatorname{span}\{(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi)\}.$ If we take $\ell_\varphi$ as another axis, we can describe the rotated graph over that line as a new function of $r$. So, $r=2-e^x\implies x=\ln(2-r).$

Picture:

[image]

By the definition:

$$x_T=\frac{M_x}{M}=\frac{\displaystyle\int_Sx\rho(x,y,z)dxdydz}{\displaystyle\int_S\rho(x,y,z)dxdydz}$$

$\begin{aligned}M=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{\ln(2-r)}e^{-x}rdxdrd\varphi&=2\pi\int_0^1r\int_0^{\ln(2-r)}e^{-x}dxdr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1r\left(-e^{-x}\right)\Big|_0^{\ln(2-r)}dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1-r\left(\frac1{2-r}-1\right)dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1\left(\frac{r}{r-2}\color{red}{+r}\right)dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1\left(\color{red}{1+r}+\frac2{r-2}\right)dr\\&=2\pi\left(\color{red}{r+\frac{r^2}2}+2\ln(2-r)\right)\Big|_0^1\\&=2\pi\left(\frac32-2\ln(2)\right)=\pi(3-4\ln(2))\end{aligned}$

$\begin{aligned}M_x=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{\ln(2-r)}xe^{-x}rdxdrd\varphi&=2\pi\int_0^1r\int_0^{\ln(2-r)}xe^{-x}dxdr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1r\left(-e^{-x}(1+x)\right)_0^{\ln(2-r)}dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1r\left(\frac{1+\ln(2-r)}{r-2}+1\right)dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1\left(\frac{r}{r-2}+\frac{r}{r-2}\ln(2-r)+r\right)dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^1\left(1+\frac2{r-2}+\ln(2-r)+\frac{2\ln(2-r)}{r-2}+r\right)dr\\&=2\pi\left(\int_0^1dr+2\int_0^1\frac{dr}{r-2}+\int_0^1\ln(2-r)dr+2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2-r)}{r-2}dr+\int_0^1rdr\right)\\&=2\pi\left(1+2\ln(2-r)\Big|_0^1+\int_0^1\int_1^{2-r}\frac1tdtdr-\color{red}{\ln(2)^2}+\frac12\right)\end{aligned}$

$\int_0^1\ln(2-r)dr=\int_0^1\int_1^{2-r}\frac{dt}tdr:$
$0\le r\le 1,1\le t\le 2-r\iff 1\le t\le 2, 0\le r\le 2-t,$ so
$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^1\ln(2-r)dr=\int_0^1\int_1^{2-r}\frac{dt}tdr&=\int_1^2\int_0^{2-t}\frac{dr}tdt\\&=\int_1^2\frac1t(2-t)dt=\int_1^2\left(\frac2t-1\right)dt=\left(2\ln(t)-t\right)\Big|_1^2\\&=2\ln(2)-2+1\\&=2\ln(2)-1\end{aligned}$$

So, $M_x=2\pi\left(\frac12-\ln^2(2)\right)=\pi(1-2\ln^2(2)),M=\pi(3-4\ln(2))$ Finally, $x_T=\frac{M_x}{M}=\frac{3-4\ln(2)}{1-2\ln^2(2)}.$

**EDIT:**

The mistakes have been marked in red for future readers. Previously, I had also swapped $M_x$ and $M$. Now the result coincides with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT...since this is a volume of revolution around the $x$ axis and the density is dependent only on $x$, you could do this much more simply as $$\bar{x}=\frac{\pi\int_0^{\ln2}\rho xy^2dx}{\pi\int_0^{\ln2}\rho y^2dx}$$